# Consulta para mostrar la disponibilidad de horarios para una cita

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola estoy bloqueada tratando de mostrar la disponibilidad del horario de un médico para proceder agendar una cita, la tabla donde realizo la consulta es la siguiente:

```
create table tblcitamedica(
citId int primary key identity(1,1),
horId int, --Id del horario
pacId int, --Id del paciente
docId int, --Id del doctor
citaFechaAgendacion DATE,
citEstado int
);

insert into tblcitamedica values(1,1,1,'2021-02-22',2);
insert into tblcitamedica values(2,2,1,'2021-02-22',2);
insert into tblcitamedica values(3,3,2,'2021-02-23',2);
```

La tabla de horarios esta definida de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento realizar es una consulta donde me muestre el el id del horario y la hora inicial y final concatenado, para después pasarlo a un "select". La consulta que tengo no me funciona por que me muestra todos los horarios.

```
SELECT h.horId as Id, h.horInicio+'-'+h.horFin as Horario from tblhorario as h where h.horEstado='A'
except select c.horId,null from tblcitamedica as c 
where c.citaFechaAgendacion = '2021-02-22' and c.docId=1
```

Tomando en cuenta los registros de la tabla "citamedica"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que me retorna la consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el resultado esperado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu tabla cita el id del horario, paciente y doctor son claves foráneas?

Comment: @Jefferson Cuji Sí, no los puse por que la db es muy grande para subir todas las cardinalidades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes especificar el nombre de las columnas del horario en la segunda en lugar de null, ya que "except" tiene como regla que las consultas comparadas deben tener el mismo número de columnas y los mismos tipos de datos (o por lo menos, los tipos de datos sean comparables) en el mismo orden.

```
SELECT h.horId as Id,h.horInicio+'-'+h.horFin as Horario from tblhorario as h
except select h2.horId as Id,h2.horInicio+'-'+h2.horFin as Horario 
from tblcitamedica as c join tblhorario as h2 on h2.horId=c.horId and 
c.citaFechaAgendacion='2021-02-22' and c.docId=1 and h2.horEstado='A'
```

Otras formas de lograr el mismo resultado podría ser usando not exists, not in o left join /is null son equivalentes pero difieren cuando están involucrados valores null. Cada situación es diferente, puedes probar y comparar cual de todos tiene un mejor rendimiento para  tu caso.

Con left join obtiene todos los registros de la tabla izquierda y de la tabla derecha aquellos que cumplan alguna condición, dependiendo el caso puede ser menos eficiente, ya que no intenta omitir los valores ya coincidentes en la tabla de la derecha, devolviendo todos los resultados y "filtrándolos".

```
select h.horId as Id,h.horInicio+'-'+h.horFin as Horario from tblhorario as h
left join tblcitamedica as c on c.horId=h.horId and 
c.citaFechaAgendacion='2021-02-22' and c.docId=1
where c.horId is null and h.horEstado='A';
```

Con not exists y not in, si alguna fila de una subconsulta retorna null, todo el operador not in se evaluará como false o desconocido y no se retornará registros. En cambio el operador exists no puede devolver null ya que verifica si existe o no una fila en la subconsulta y solo retornaría verdadero o falso.

Cuando la columna que se usa en la subconsulta para comparar con la tabla externa puede tener nulos, debe tener en cuenta cual de las dos usar.

```
SELECT h.horId as Id,h.horInicio+'-'+h.horFin as Horario 
from tblhorario as h where 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT horId FROM tblcitamedica where h.horId=horId and 
citaFechaAgendacion='2021-02-22' and docId=2) and h.horEstado='A'

SELECT h.horId as Id,h.horInicio+'-'+h.horFin as Horario 
FROM tblhorario as h 
WHERE h.horId not in (select horId from tblcitamedica where 
citaFechaAgendacion='2021-02-23' and docId=2) and h.horEstado='A'
```

Answer (score 2):

Si tu consulta se limita a las citas de un doctor y de un día en particular, esta consulta, entiendo podría resolverlo:

```
SELECT h.horId as Id, 
       h.horInicio + '-' + h.horFin as Horario 
       from tblhorario h
       WHERE h.horId NOT IN (SELECT horId
                                    FROM tblcitamedica
                                    WHERE citaFechaAgendacion = '2021-02-22' 
                                          AND docId = 1)
```

Se muestran todos los horarios que aún no han sido asignados al día y médico en cuestión.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `LEFT JOIN`, y extraer las filas, que sean null.

```
SELECT h.horId as Id, h.horInicio+'-'+h.horFin as Horario 
from 
tblhorario as h
left join tblcitamedica as c on c.horId = h.horid
where h.horEstado='A'
and
c.citId is null
```

[image: Resultado]

La mejor manera de entender el como se hace, es ver como se forma la union de los conjuntos.

```
SELECT h.horId as Id, h.horInicio+'-'+h.horFin as Horario, c.*
from 
tblhorario as h
left join tblcitamedica as c on c.horId = h.horid
where h.horEstado='A'
```

[image: Resultado Left Join]

Cuando se enlazan los registros de tblhorario con tblcitamédica, por el horid ves los que no son del criterio seleccionado.

Si lo quieres hacer con el operador `except`

```
SELECT h.horId as Id, h.horInicio+'-'+h.horFin as Horario
from 
tblhorario as h
except 
select h.horId as Id, h.horInicio+'-'+h.horFin as Horario
from tblhorario h
inner join tblcitamedica as c on c.horId = h.horid
where h.horEstado='A'
```

Ambos conjuntos (el de antes del operador, y el de después, aunque sean varias tablas), tienen que retornar lo mismo.